# Jinjna2 how to style a string based on values in the string

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Hello and Thank you in advance.

I have the following string generated by an SQL statement.

1kg-afr;0.4:1kg-eas;0.2:1kg-eur;0.3:gtex;0.2

I want to style background color based on the value? I am able to parse the string in Jinja and set the color. How do I redisplay the string as a string with styling applied?

[image: example output]

example jinja2 template snipet

d[9] is the string.
This would handle the case where the entry was 0.0 would add logic for the other colors etc. The color logic would go into the css. Need to see how recombine the list as a single item with the style maintained.

```
{% set list1 = d[9].split(':') %}
          {% for Hval in list1 %}
          {% set Hlist = Hval.split(';') %}
             {% if Hlist[1] == '0.0' %}
               <td class="Hzero"> {{ Hlist| join(";") }}</td>
             {% else %}
               <td> {{ Hval }}</td>
             {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to do this inside a jinja2 template? Python > jinja2 for processing logic. You might consider doing all the logic in python and just passing the values and formatting into jinja2.

Comment: As I was developing the jinja2 template I started to realize it probably wasn't going to be the best way to do it. I will generate the html in python and pass that to jinja.